# Light weight touch events lib for mobile html5 apps?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile, sencha-touch

I'm looking for something like Sencha Touch that isn't so heavy. I don't want any templating, design, theming. I just want the raw functionality of the touch events and transitions.

Anything like this out there?

It should heavily rely on css for transitions.

Should I just roll my own?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think I might try http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 looks good so far and css heavy!

Comment: You can also try this one http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/

Comment: @llya Thanks, yea I looked into that but iScoll has many more touch behaviors baked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might try http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 looks good so far and css heavy!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to roll one your own, since it's no big deal and easy to do.

Comment: Are touch events well standardized across platforms?

Comment: They are across webkit based browsers, which Android and iOS use. I'm not sure about Windows and Blackberry. But if not, I'm pretty sure that they will be soon on those platforms as well

Answer (score 0):

Touch events are standard for Android and iOS.  The problem with most frameworks is they target Webkit browers, which Blackberry and Windows will not be supported.

check out https://github.com/appmobi/aux for a lightweight UI framework with transitions.  If you need widgets to drop in, you can get some at https://github.com/appmobi/aux_web